# Wie sagt man "To have a beef with someone" auf Deutsch?

Tags: idiom

Ich habe Probleme mit diesem Typ in der Kneipe.

> I have a beef with this guy in the Bar.

Wie sagt man "to have a beef with somebody" auf Deutsch?

Comment: *Mit jemandem Beef haben* ist verbreiteter Slang, vorallem in der Hip-Hop-Szene.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Man kann mit jemandem *Stress haben* (umgangssprachlich, anstatt "Streit" im Standardeutschen).

Oder man hat mit jemandem "ein Hühnchen zu rupfen" oder noch "eine Rechnung offen". Die letzten beiden Beispiele gehen aber mehr in die Richtung "having a bone to pick with so.", d.h. man erwartet da noch ein einzelnes Streitgespräch/Gelegenheit für Rache.

Comment: ein Hühnchen zu rupfen passt sehr gut zu dem metaphorischen Bezug auf Essen.